# Oracle retaining Grant for the re-created object

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

I've a grant for table T, I want this grant to be pertained after:

```
drop table T;
create table T(...);
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9003.htm#i2061306) (emphasis mine):

> Dropping a table invalidates dependent objects **and removes object privileges on the table**. If you want to re-create the table, then you must regrant object privileges on the table, re-create the indexes, integrity constraints, and triggers for the table, and respecify its storage parameters. Truncating and replacing have none of these effects. Therefore, removing rows with the TRUNCATE statement can be more efficient than dropping and re-creating a table.

Therefore you need to explicitly add the `grant` statements to your script after the `create table` statement.

Comment: Can I get away with using roles? Or information about dropped objects gets wiped off from roles too?

Comment: @user1514042 Roles won't work either. A possible work-around is to introduce a layer of indirection with a view: create a view on top of the table to be dropped and then grant the privileges on the view. The view, although invalid, will not be dropped together with its base table and the privileges on the view will persist.

Answer (score 2):

No.  At the moment you drop the object, any grants on that object will be removed.  When you create a new object, even if that object happens to have the same name as the old object, you'll need to re-grant whatever privileges you want on the new object.  That's one reason that dropping and re-creating an object is seldom a good idea-- why do you need to drop and re-create your table?

You could, of course, identify all the grants before you drop the object and then re-create those after you create the new object.  You could do that either by querying the various data dictionary tables like `dba_tab_privs`) or by using the [`dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BABFBDDG) to get the DDL for the grants.